# IronPython 2.7 with NetworkX 1.8.1

Tags: python, ironpython, networkx

I am trying to use NetworkX 1.8.1 with Ironpython 2.7. Now I've been stuck to this problem for about 12 hours so far.... but without any luck. Whenever I tried to import networkX, I am having 'non implemented' error as below:

> NotImplementedError: The method or operation is not implemented.  File
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython
>   2.7\lib\site-packages\networkx\algorithms\isomorphism\matchhelpers.py",
>   line 23, in copyfunc return types.FunctionType(f.func_code,
>   f.func_globals, name or f.name, .....

I tested networkx 1.6, but the same result. It seems that there are some problems in line 23 of matchhelpers.py, but I could never figured it out. Can anyone look into this problem? I am so desperate.....

(And also please recommend me any alternative Graph libraries compatible with IronPython)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in IronPython - types.FunctionType resolves to a constructor call that throws a `NotImplementedException` (see https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Languages/IronPython/IronPython/Runtime/PythonFunction.cs#L72).

It's old code, so I'm not sure why it does that. I've opened [issue #35180](https://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/35180) to track it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Hardy. I asked this to the Git forum of networkx, and gurus temporarily made it possible to run networkx on Ironpython. Hope things will be completely fixed soon!